# Display/Format the column name in a second row in a pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, column-width

Is there any way I can display the column name in the second line in the given df (refer to the image)?

Often I work with data that have considerably longer names and I have to scroll horizontally back and forth to check the data. It would be nice if I could simply push the names to the second row so that I can see the whole df on the display. Column renaming isn't an option here.

sample image of the df

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA4rD.png)

sample df

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'hdg1_mv_an2l_mv_carroent_torque_tot': {0: 46.20000076293945,
  1: 4.829999923706055,
  2: 10.229999542236328,
  3: 10.100000381469727,
  4: 14.279999732971191},
 'hdg1_mv_an2l_mv_carroent_refvellineal': {0: 12.020000457763672,
  1: 15.0,
  2: 15.0,
  3: 15.0,
  4: 15.0},
 'hdg1_mv_an2l_mv_carroent_vellineal': {0: 0.019999999552965164,
  1: 14.930000305175781,
  2: 2.109999895095825,
  3: 14.789999961853027,
  4: 4.25},
 'hdg1_ms_chapa_espesor_mm': {0: 320.0, 1: 89.0, 2: 89.0, 3: 89.0, 4: 69.0},
 'hdg1_ms_chapa_ancho': {0: 975.0, 1: 600.0, 2: 600.0, 3: 600.0, 4: 1000.0},
 'hdg1_mv_an2l_mv_carroent_tiro': {0: 3211.0,
  1: 208.0,
  2: 599.0,
  3: 597.0,
  4: 876.0},
 'hdg1_ms_do_a706_4_ace_freno': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0},
 'hdg1_ms_sec_carroentrada_driver': {0: 5.0, 1: 5.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 5.0, 4: 5.0},
 'cumsum_group': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'thickness_group': {0: 't7', 1: 't3', 2: 't3', 3: 't3', 4: 't2'},
 'final_group': {0: 'grp47',
  1: 'no_group',
  2: 'no_group',
  3: 'no_group',
  4: 'grp8'}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this line to wrap the column names and remove the horizontal scrolling, You can also adjust the wrapping by `max-width`:

```
df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector':'th',
                            'props':[('word-wrap', ' break-word'),
                                     ('max-width','50px'),
                                     ( 'text-align', 'left')
                                    ]
                           }])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does achieve what I wanted, however, is there a way to make this change permanent?  I am applying this style on the df but it goes away next time I call it or any other df.